# How to exclude something from being replaced by gsub()

Tags: r, replace, design-patterns, matching, gsub

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm really new to R. What I'm wondering is, is there any way to specify exclusions within gsub or a similar function? 
My data will look something like this: (15: .0234 , 12: .0151), and I want to replace the leading 15 with another item matching this (a: .b , c: .d) pattern. However, just calling gsub replaces both the leading 15 with the new pattern, and the 15 following the decimal point. It wouldn't work to simply tell it to replace only the first occurence, because there a lot of these patterns nested. What I'm thinking is to exclude numbers following a decimal point and followed by a whitespace from the gsub - is this even possible?

Comment: Seconding @DWin 's answer, it would be very helpful to see the code that produced your data. If the data you'd like to run `gsub()` on is stored as an object called `myData`, could you post the output of `dput(myData)`?

Answer (score 4):

If you set `perl=TRUE` in gsub then you can use positive and negative look aheads or look behinds which might solve your problem, for example the pattern `15(?=:)` will match a 15 that is followed by a colon (but will not match/replace the colon) and will not match any 15s that are not followed by a colon.  The pattern `(?

See `?regex` in the 'perl' section for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you how to replace only "leading 15"s but you have not offered code that produces test cases where you do or don't wnat these nested patterns replaced, so this is a bit of a guess.

```
 vec <- c('15: .0234' , '12: .0151')
 gsub("^15", "aa", vec)
#[1] "aa: .0234" "12: .0151"
```

The "^" symbol in a regex pattern indicates the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with regular expressions, I would consider parsing the strings into `(a, b, c, d, ...)` vectors. For example, you could do:

```
strsplit("15: .0234, 12: .0151", ": |, ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "15"     ".0234" "12"    ".0151"
```

Then it should be much easier to do substitutions using functions like `==`, `match`, `%in%`, `[`, etc.

When you are done, you can put things back together using `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do an inclusion rather than an exclusion.

Firstly, set up some test data:

```
test <- c("15: .0234 , 12: .0151")
```

An example to replace a 15 at the start of the string (the ^ does this).

```
gsub("^15","x",test)
[1] "x: .0234 , 12: .0151"
```

A more general example to replace any number at the start of the string.

```
gsub("^([0-9]+)","x",test)
[1] "x: .0234 , 12: .0151"
```

An example to remove any number followed by a colon (:) and replace with an x and a colon

```
gsub("([0-9]+):","x:",test)
[1] "x: .0234 , x: .0151"
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you?

```
(foo <- "15: .0234 , 12: .0151")
# "15: .0234 , 12: .0151"
(bar <- "a: .b , c: .d")
# "a: .b , c: .d"
gsub("^15",bar, foo)
# "a: .b , c: .d: .0234 , 12: .0151"
```

If not please provide some example data and also an example object showing what your end goal is. A string of how your data could look like, it's the the sentence 'It wouldn't work to simply tell it to replace only the first occurence, because there a lot of these patterns nested' that is a little unclear to me. You want find '15' within a string, but not if it at the end or part of the a number that begins with a decimal point?

Have you read the help file `?gsub`?

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("^15","a: .b , c: .d","15: .0234 , 12: .0151")
```

Would this solve your problem?